# How to Add CMB2 fields in my custom cmb2 field..?

Tags: php, wordpress, cmb2

I'm create my own cmb2 custom field. I want to add another custom field or default CMB2 fields in my custom field... it is possible ?

I created and render the custom field using cmb2 documentation and render the field like this **cmb2_render_{field-type}**

```
function cmb2_render_callback_for_text_email( $field, $escaped_value, $object_id, $object_type, $field_type_object ) {
    echo $field_type_object->input( array( 'type' => 'email' ) );
}

add_action( 'cmb2_render_text_email', 'cmb2_render_callback_for_text_email', 10, 5 );
```

I'm try to add another custom field into callback function but not getting any result.